# Propagating forsythia via cuttings: remove leaf buds?

Tags: leaves, propagation, cuttings

I am attempting to propagate forsythia cuttings in potting soil. I made sure each dormant twig had one bud underground and one bud above, and dipped each twig in rooting hormone. Then I mostly covered the pot in plastic to lock in moisture while still allowing some ventilation. Leaf buds are appearing now, about one week after "planting". Should I remove the leaf buds so the twigs focus their energy on roots?

Any other forsythia propagation advice is welcome.

[image]